# How come I can't make this script work in Joomla 3

Tags: jquery, html, loops, joomla3.0, cross-fade

I am trying to get a basic loop and cross-fade jquery function to work in Joomla 3 on sequential DIV layers.  Everything I read doesn't seem to clarify what I am doing wrong.
Here is the div HTML:

```
<div class="quotes">
<p><i>"Quote 1 with many lines of text"
<br>
Blessings,</i></p>
<p><b><i>Sherry</i></b>
</div>

<div class="quotes">
<p><i>
"Quote 2 with many lines of text"
<br>
Take care my friend,</i></p>
<p><b><i>Liz</i></b>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
(function() {

var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;

function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}

showNextQuote();

})();
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
.quotes {display: none;}
```

I was able to get the code to work in jsfiddle but not my Joomla 3 website.  You can see it functioning here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4mKw/4290/

Please direct me on how to make it function in Joomla 3.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check console for any jQuery error? Also try changing $(".quotes"); to jQuery(".quotes");

Comment: Not sure if I did it right, I replaced the part that you suggested... Nothing changed.  Do I need to put the entire script between the <script> mark up inline in the body or somewhere else?  The problem is I don't know how to declare it between the <head> markup inside of a Joomla 3 template.

Comment: If possible can you send me url to check?

Comment: [74.220.219.51/~bobsexpe](http://74.220.219.51/~bobsexpe) -- on the right hand side there are 2 sections one called **Reader Testimonials** and one called Reader Testimonials 2... The **Reader Testimonials 2** is the one I am trying to get to work. @Ifran

Comment: I checked and I could not find any JS code you provded on that site. You can put that in index.php of your active template.

Comment: so you are saying jquery must be put inside the index.php file and not inside a module?  Does it matter where I put it inside that file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126539/discussion-between-irfan-and-derek-holliday).